# Is there any way to getResult between Kotlin activity and Java activity?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-activity

I am trying to pass data from Java Activity to Kotlin Activity.
Is that possible?

kotlin side:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

if (requestCode == newFriendActivityRequestCode && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
    data?.getStringExtra(manualActivity.EXTRA_REPLY)?.let {
        
        val friendViewModel: FriendViewModel by viewModels {
            FriendViewModelFactory((application as FriendsApplication).repository)
        }

        val friend = Friend(1, it)
        friendViewModel.insert(friend)
    }
}
```

Java side:

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
resultIntent.putExtra("name", name);
setResult(RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
finish();
```

kotlin ref for code:
https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view-kotlin#14

Comment: you get the data from the intent, you are not using the key you used when you set the data

Comment: Yes you can, the language the two activities are written in doesn't matter.

Comment: Of course they share the same compiler

Answer (score 0):

according your code at side activity for java you send data with key `name` but at side activity with kotlin you receive wrong key the correct code like this

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {

    if (requestCode ==1 /*request code use to start activity java code*/ && resultCode ==
        Activity.RESULT_OK
            ) {
        val name =data?.getStringExtra("name")?.let {    // name key you send it from java activity
             return@let it
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    }
    
}
```